# Where can I find the default /system/lib for Lollipop

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, system

I have a rooted Alcatel 5017 A and I wanna check the libraries on the system (I think I got hacked) can anyone show me the default content of system/lib for this phone? Thank you all!

Also, I would like to decompile some system process in order to check if their code had been changed, if anyone knows how to reverse engineer the com.google... processes I would love that

Comment: Flashing stock ROM or Factory Firmware looks more feasible option than looking for default libraries of a specific device and reverse engineering its binaries.

Comment: can you give a quick hint on what it means to flash stock rom ? The internet only have tutorials but no explanation

Comment: See [this](https://consumingtech.com/alcatel-pixi-3-4-5-5017a-stock-rom/) and [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/root-alcatel-one-touch-pixi-34-official-t3193624). Flashing ROM means installing a fresh copy of Android OS.